# how to fit iOS webview screen with rotation and zoom enabled

Tags: ios, webview, screen-orientation

My app is simply loading a webview on 4th generation iPad.

It has 768 x 1024 portrait and 1024 x 768 landscape view size.

However the content I am loading is 760 x 1014.

The app supports rotations and zoom.

If the view is loaded I want it to be fit on full screen of portrait as well as landscape with scroll bar.

so I added a meta tag on the header like this

```
<meta name="viewport" id="view" content="width=760, user-scalable=yes">
```

also on my sdk

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
mainWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
mainWebView.delegate = self;

[mainWebView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth)];
mainWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
mainWebView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

for(id subview in mainWebView.subviews) {
    if([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
        ((UIScrollView *)subview).bounces = NO;
        ((UIScrollView *)subview).alwaysBounceVertical = NO;
        ((UIScrollView *)subview).alwaysBounceHorizontal = NO;
        ((UIScrollView *)subview).bouncesZoom = NO;
        ((UIScrollView *)subview).maximumZoomScale = 2.0;
        ((UIScrollView *)subview).minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    }
}
[self.view addSubview:self.mainWebView];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://my app"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[mainWebView loadRequest:request];
}
```

along with these

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
if (interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
    NSLog(@"Rotated Landscape");
    [mainWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById(\"view\").setAttribute('content', 'width=1014');"]];
}
return YES;}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
NSLog(@"didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation");
if(fromInterfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || fromInterfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
    [mainWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById(\"view\").setAttribute('content', 'width=1014');"]];
    [mainWebView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth)];
    mainWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
} else if (fromInterfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || fromInterfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
    [mainWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById(\"view\").setAttribute('content', 'width=760');"]];
    [mainWebView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth)];
    mainWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
}}
```

P.S shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is not even being called.

please tell me what is wrong with my code. any suggestion would be helpful

Comment: You can write `for (UIScrollView *subview in mainWebView.subviews)` and then you can avoid all the ugly and repetitive casting that hurts my eyes.

Comment: Try this meta tags in your html file:
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.6">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="YES">

Comment: and one more line in your XCode project: [mainWebView.superview setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];

Comment: in your sdk ?! you mean in your code ?